# xCode command-line > foundation problem

Tags: objective-c, macos, foundation

I'm trying to set up a command-line > foundation "hello world" project. (as written in the book 'learning objective C for mac') ...When I select 'build & run' with the default settings  for this project I get 4 errors, without modifying any code!?

errors:

```
stdarg.h: no such file or directory
float.h: no such file or directory
xmmintrin.h: no such file or directory
expected specifier-qualifier-list
```

Comment: Can you please post your code? It'll really help.

Comment: image of the error: http://www.ikwildesign.nl/temp/error.jpg

Comment: #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // insert code here...
    NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
    [pool release];
    return 0;
}

Comment: and the header: //
// Prefix header for all source files of the 'Untitled' target in the 'Untitled' project.
//

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif

Comment: What system are you running on?

Comment: Intel based Macbook white model 2006

Comment: Still haven't found an answer :( Anyone familiar with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by Apple Support!

Project was running under 10.4 SDK instead of 10.6 SDK. (Changed this by selecting the Project title in the left pane and then the 'info' option)